# Is there an easy way to demonstrate the recurrence relation on vector spaces over fields with q elements?

Tags: matrix, vector

For finite dimensional vector spaces over a field with q elements:  The number of k dimensional subspaces of an n dimensional vector space, [n,k] is equal to the number of k-1 dimensional subspaces of an n-1 dimensional vector space, plus q^k times the number of k dimensional subspaces of an n-1 dimensional vector space.  In other words, [n,k] = [n-1,k-1] + q^k*[n-1,k].

It appears that the number of times that any particular vector appears in a k dimensional subspace of an n dimensional space is equal to [n-1,k-1] while the number of subspaces missing this particular vector is q^k*[n-1,k].

Is there a way to prove this statement which I am making based on staring at subspaces of small dimensions.

Comment: So the field  is a finite field $F_{q}$?

Comment: Yes the vector space is over a finite field with q elements where q is a prime power.

Comment: Can you clarify in what way the question is related to the *Mathematica* software?